# mysql select distinct column based on group by column

Tags: mysql

Hi I have the following columns

```
| id | name | category|
|  1 | sam  | doctor  |
|  2 | tom  | doctor  |
|  3 | pam  | nurse   |
|  4 | gum  | nurse   |
|  5 | tom  | doctor  |
|  6 | lim  | doctor  |
```

I want to run a query to choose distinct names based on category where `name`column is unique to get below

```
| id | name | category|
|  1 | sam  | doctor  |
|  2 | tom  | doctor  |
|  3 | pam  | nurse   |
|  4 | gum  | nurse   |
|  6 | lim  | nurse   |
```

It baffles me

Comment: which id do you want to choose? do you care?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `min`:

```
select min(id), name, category
from yourtable
group by name, category
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe6bd/1)

---

If you truly just want distinct names, then since you're using mysql, this would work as well (but return random ids and categories).  If you need specific ids/categories, you'll need to define them in an aggregate (as in the previous solution):

```
select id, name, category
from yourtable
group by name
```